# Python script works well on its own, but crashes when running it form another script using Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, process, pywinauto

I would like to execute a python script **sequence.py** by clicking a button on **usercontrol.py**, all the necessary code I want to initiate is located in **sequence.py** `main()` function sequentially.

The script **sequence.py** works fine by itself, and if I try to call the script from another script simply like this **test.py**:

```
import sequence as sq

sq.main()
```

it will also run fine.

But if I try to run it by clicking a button in **usercontrol.py** which contains variuos Tkinter GUI elements:

```
import sequence as sq
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
             .... CODE ....
             self.start_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_1, text="Start", command=sq.main)
             .... CODE ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

It will crash at the crucial first steps of **sequence.py**.

While I think this has more to do with Tkinter, I am trying to automate a legacy software using ***pywinauto***, the huge stack of code in **sequence.py** works entirely fine, except the main thing where It should open the process for automation, the window is not opened, I get a back telling me that there is no process to move windows, then after that the windows appears.
**sequence.py** code:

```
import time, pywinauto
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

def main():
    # Step 1: Connects to the Application, creates directories and calibrates the main window to user monitor settings
    main_processName = "EFrame2"
    try: 
    .... CODE (works fine) ....
    except Exception:
        user_name = input('Name: ')
        user_password = input('Password: ')
        send_keys('^%e') # CTRL + ALT + E shortcut to open the application 
        time.sleep(5)
        main_pid = application.process_from_module(module = main_processName)
        main_process = application.Application().connect(process = main_pid, timeout=10)
        main_dlg = main_process.window(class_name="TFormMDI")
        monitor_set_position(main_dlg) # it crashes at this function because main_dlg it not shown
        connect_sequence(main_process, main_pid, user_name, user_password)
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The most frustrating thing, is that all variables are returning the values as it should on debug mode.. It still finds the process and connects to it. **Then I get the Traceback, and instantly the Windows that should be shown prior - appears.**

To summarize, using a tkinter button to initiate the script with pywinauto somehow doesn't work when launching a new process, maybe this could be a processing/thread problem? Any pointers to solving this issue are welcome.

**EDIT 1 (adding Traceback if needed):**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 553, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "c:\Dokumentai\auto\module\sequence.py", line 567, in main
    monitor_set_position(main_dlg)
  File "c:\Dokumentai\auto\module\sequence.py", line 95, in monitor_set_position
    main_dlg.move_window(x=0, y=0, width=800, height=800, repaint=True)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 396, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 203, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'class_name': 'TFormMDI', 'backend': 'win32', 'process': 10812}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, if someone would have a similar issue in the future with Tkinter.

The problem was Threading, in my **sequence.py**, I was using timing functions like `time.sleep(5)`, and it was causing problems, lagging ant etc. when using on a single thread together with GUI. I don't understand the details about threading, I am beginner myself, but you can probably count on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnrCpA1xJPQ&ab_channel=Codemy.com) to help you out.

The ultimate change that I have done that fixed everything for me is in **usercontrol.py**, I have changed the command of the button and put the start script into a function:

```
import sequence as sq
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import threading

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
             .... CODE ....
             self.start_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_1, text="Start", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.initiate_weekly_report_module).start())
             .... CODE ....
    def initiate_weekly_report_module(self):
        sq.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```